# How to avoid keyring password while submitting job on slurm?

Tags: r, slurm, cds.copernicus

I'm submitting a job to download cds data on slurm. submitting it returns the error instantly:

```
slurmstepd: error: execve(): /var/spool/slurmd/job....../slurm_script: Not a directory
```

running script directly using Rscript file.R asks for keyring password.
Since I'll be submitting the job on slurm hiw do I overcome this?
Rscript that im using can be found here: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CUSF/Download+CDS+ERA5+data+using+R

Comment: Having a similar issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ailf sadly No. I used Rstudio instead.